# How to conclude this integral (bivariate normal distribution).

Tags: real-analysis

I`m trying to solve the next integral:

$$\large \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{y}^{\infty}(e^x-e^y)\frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2-2 \rho x y}{2(1-\rho^2)}} dx\ dy$$

I have tried to use the next change of variable: $u:=x-py$, so the integral takes the next expression:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{y-py}^{\infty}(e^{u+py}-e^y)\frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}} du \; e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} dy $$

However, I do not know whow to continue, since the error function remains inside the integral.

Comment: Did you try to switch to polar coordinates? You are integrating over $y\leq x$. The result should be related to Bessel functions, I guess.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio How could the integral be reformulated in terms of polar coordenates? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  I know the result you have brought is right cause I have probed it numericaly, if you could detail a bit more the second and third equailities I would be able to solve it also analitically. Thanks:)

Comment: I just applied a change of variable, followed by an application of Fubini's theorem. That gives an integral over $\mathbb{R}$ (in $dy$) that is not difficult to compute. We compute it, then we compute the equivalent one-variable integral in $dz$ that gives an error function multiplied by something manageable. You may check that the computations below are right also with a CAS.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  To compute the second equality, that is, to get that the result of the integral is: $\sqrt{\pi*(1+p)}$, I have to probe that $$y-\frac{(z^2+(2-2p)z*y+(2-2p)y^2)}{2(1-p^2)}=(-y^2/(1+p))-((2z-1)+(p-z)^2))/(4(1-p))$$, to be able to apply: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^2}{a}} du=\sqrt{a\pi}$$... but it seems to be different... am I in the correct way?

Comment: Obviously the result of the integral you are talking about is not $\sqrt{\pi(\rho+1)}$, it is $$\sqrt{\pi(\rho+1)} \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{(2z-1)+(\rho-z)^2}{4(1-\rho)}\right).$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  Yes, that is! But to get this result, the next equality must be true, mustn´t it? $$y-\frac{(z^2+(2-2p)z*y+(2-2p)y^2)}{2(1-p^2)}=\frac{-y^2}{1+p}-\left(-\frac{(2z-1)+(\rho-z)^2}{4(1-\rho)}\right)$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio if it not true I think I am quite lost.... :(

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio According to this the equality is not verified, there is my confusion... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y-%28z%5E2%2B%282-2p%29zy%2B%282-2p%29y%5E2%29%2F%282%281-p%5E2%29%29%3D%28-y%5E2%2F%281%2Bp%29%29-%28%282z-1%29%2B%28p-z%29%5E2%29%29%2F%284%281-p%29%29

Comment: You are confusing a function with its primitive. Please carefully check my solution below before asking for further details.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I have read it. I think I am not confusing it. I mean: $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(y-\frac{z^2+(2-2\rho)zy+(2-2\rho)y^2}{2(1-p^2)}\right)\,dy=\\ = \sqrt{\pi(\rho+1)} \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{(2z-1)+(\rho-z)^2}{4(1-\rho)}\right)\Longrightarrow$$ $$\exp\left(-\frac{(2z-1)+(\rho-z)^2}{4(1-\rho)}\right) \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{y^2}{1+p}}$$, so the previous equality must be hold.

Comment: You have to integrate that function with respect to $dz$, hence you cannot bring the exponential piece out of the integral.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I thought that first of all, as we were integrating with respct to $dy$, we could take z as constant. All in all, it is okay, I have tried but it is clear that something is wrong in my understanding. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I have read carefully your answer and achieved to understand all but the second equality. I am not able to complete squares and obtain the one-variable integral. I would appreciate if you could detail a bit more this step. Thanks a lot! :)